# How to listen for custom events triggered by jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, event-handling, custom-events

I'm using a jQuery plugin that schedules appointments in 3 steps. Each time you move on to the next step, the plugin triggers a custom event. I would like to listen for this event and perform some actions outside of the plugin. I thought it would be as simple as:

```
$(document).on('CUSTOM_EVENT', function() {
    console.log('CUSTOM_EVENT from appointment plugin just fired.');
});
```

Unfortunately, that did not work. Are events triggered from within a plugin able to be "heard" from outside the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this sample

```
$(document).on('CUSTOM_EVENT', 'CUSTOM_ELEMENT',function() {
        console.log('CUSTOM_EVENT from appointment plugin just fired.');
 });
```

Comment: That's pretty much the same thing as what I posted... with the addition of a filter. Didn't work.